# Windows API ms delays and Timer Resolution of newer PCs?

Tags: winapi, timer

It used to be your various WinAPI functions that took timeout or delay values in milliseconds had a low end of about 10ms (you choose 1ms-9ms you really get 10ms) due to the resolution of the timer tick.

Is that limitation gone in modern Windows versions and systems or does it still exist?

TIA!

Comment: Still exists, AFAIK. Resoluton can be affected by [`timeBeginPeriod()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timebeginperiod), but this is generally not recommended in most projects.

Comment: Complex matter. Bruce Dawson has great posts about all this https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2021/01/29/windows-timer-resolution-the-great-rule-change-2/